# How to Set the height of a row With CustomCmponent lower than 30 Points In Vaadin Spreadsheet(Apache Poi)?

Tags: java, vaadin7

I'm Working with [Vaadin Spreadsheet](https://vaadin.com/spreadsheet) (1.0.0 rc1) and i'm trying to set the height of a row with custom Component lower than 30 Pts.
The problem's that the implementation of Spreadsheet class don't allow a height row lower than 30 pts for rows with custom Components.

```
public class Spreadsheet extends AbstractComponent implements HasComponents,
        Action.Container, Focusable {

    /**
     * Minimum row height for rows containing components (in points).
     */
    private static final int MINIMUM_ROW_HEIGHT_FOR_COMPONENTS = 30;
```

But i'm forced to set the size lower than 30 pts. Is there another way to do this ? 
Thank you for any Help.

```
 private final Workbook testWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            final Sheet sheet = getTestWorkbook().createSheet("Custom Components");
            Row lastRow = sheet.createRow(100);



        private final Object[][] data = {
                    { "Testing custom editors", "Boolean", "Date", "Numeric", "Button",
                            "ComboBox" },
                    { "nulls:", false, null, 0, null, null },
                    { "", true, new Date(), 5, "here is a button", comboBoxValues[0] },
                    { "", true, Calendar.getInstance(), 500.0D,
                            "here is another button", comboBoxValues[1] } };      

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
            row.setHeightInPoints(10F);
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the height like `HSSFRow r = null; r.setHeight( (short) 0x349 );`

Comment: Can you include that code in your question (by editing it) instead of in comments? It could be formatted as code and be more readable.

Comment: Can I do this Using java reflection ?